# Hibernate HQL insert Query

Tags: hibernate, hql

In Eclipse using Hibernate with a MySQL database,
I have many to many relationship between two tables `Profile` and `Fonctionnalite` and the resulting table was `T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE` with a composite primary key. I want to insert a new record in `T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE`.

These are the corresponding classes in the hbm.xml file:

```
<class name="Fonctionnalite" table="T_FONCTIONNALITE" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert ="false">
   <id name="code" column="CODE" type="java.lang.String"/>
   <property name="libelle"  column="LIBELLE"  type="java.lang.String"/>
   <property name="url"  column="URL"  type="java.lang.String"/>
  <bag name="profiles" cascade="none" table="T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE" lazy ="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="CODE_FONCTIONNALITE" />
        <many-to-many class="Profile" column="CODE_PROFILE" unique="true"/>
   </bag>
</class>

<class name="Profile" table="T_PROFILE" dynamic-update="true">
   <id name="code"  column="CODE"  type="java.lang.String"/>
   <property name="libelle"  column="LIBELLE"  type="java.lang.String"/>
   <property name="estFonctionnalitesUpdate"  column="UPDATED"  type="yes_no"/>
   <bag name="menus" cascade="all" table="T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE" lazy ="true" inverse="true">
        <key column="CODE_PROFILE" />
        <many-to-many class="Fonctionnalite" column="CODE_FONCTIONNALITE" unique="true" where="URL is not null" />
   </bag>
</class>
```

I tried to add the following entity for the table **T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE**:

```
<class name="proFonc" table="T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE" dynamic-update="false" dynamic-insert ="false">
   <composite-id>
       <key-many-to-one name="codepro" entity-name="Profile" foreign-key="code" column="CODE_PROFILE"></key-many-to-one>
      <key-many-to-one name="codefonc" entity-name="Fonctionnalite" foreign-key="code" column="CODE_FONCTIONNALITE"></key-many-to-one>
       </composite-id>
</class>
```

I got this exception:

```
An association from the table T_PROFILE_FONCTIONNALITE refers to an unmapped class: Fonctionnalite
```

Another problem is how to write the query itself.

This is the method prefered [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm)

```
String hql = "INSERT INTO Employee(firstName, lastName, salary)"  + 
             "SELECT firstName, lastName, salary FROM old_employee";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);
```

But i used to do queries with parameters like:

```
 <query name="insertpf" type="hql" >
    <body>
    <![CDATA[
        insert into  proFonc values 
    ]]>
    </body>
    <body param="proid"> 
    <![CDATA[
        (proid ,
          ]]>
    </body>
    <body param="foncid"> 
    <![CDATA[
        foncid)
          ]]>
    </body>
</query>
```

Of course, this is syntactically wrong, because I created it, please help me if I am not using the select, nor the session to get the values to be inserted, because I have them in variables. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my problem:

NO NEED TO ADD ENTITY!, NO NEED TO ADD QUERY!. USE `saveOrUpdate`.

In dao/hibernate/modeldaoimpl.java I have this method:

```
    public void saveOrUpdate(final Object entity) throws DaoException{
    try {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
    }

}
```

This method updates every entity taking its relationships with other entities in consideration. So only fill `profile` entity with its `fonctionalities` (look at the `bag` tag in the question for `profile`), and call this method.

In my Security service interface:

```
public ResultatDTO saveProfil(ProfileDTO profilDTO, Integer idUser)
        throws ServiceExecutionException;
```

Implementation:

```
public ResultatDTO saveProfil(Profile pr, Integer idUser)
        throws ServiceExecutionException {
    ResultatDTO resultatDTO = new ResultatDTO();
    try {
        pr.addAllMenus(getfucs(pr)); //fill your entity (`bag` menus).

        modelDao.saveOrUpdate(profil);// call saveorupdate

        resultatDTO.setResult(//obj);
        return resultatDTO;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServiceExecutionException(e);
    }
}
```

Body:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(final Object entity) throws DaoException{
    try {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);
    }

}.
```